# How to use Fontawsome Pro icons in mkdocs material

Tags: font-awesome, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have purchased a License for the Fontawesome Pro Icons package and was wondering how I can use the pro library kit in mkdocs material?
I currently use the free fonts like this, for example:

```
:fontawesome-solid-user-secret:
```

But I would like to use the "thin" version which is part of the pro package, like this:

```
:fontawesome-thin-user-secret:
```

How can I achieve that? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a `custom_dir` in `mkdocs.yml` if you haven't already:

```yaml
theme:
  custom_dir: docs/.overrides  # Relative to mkdocs.yml. Can be whatever you want.
```

Then [download Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/download), extract it, and move the *contents* of the `svgs` directory (*not* including the folder itself) to `{CUSTOM_DIR}/.icons/fontawesome`. For example, if your `custom_dir` is `docs/.overrides`, you would move the contents of the `svgs` directory to `docs/.overrides/.icons/fontawesome`. Everything else that came with the download is safe to delete.

Your `custom_dir` should look like this:

```
.
└── .icons/
    └── fontawesome/
        ├── brands
        ├── duotone
        ├── light
        ├── regular
        ├── sharp-regular
        ├── sharp-solid
        ├── solid
        └── thin
```

You can then use Font Awesome Pro icons in the same way you already do the free ones (e.g. `:fontawesome-thin-user-secret:` will work as written).